# How to determine the end of va_arg list?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have a function `foo(char *n, ...);`
I need to get and use all of optional `char` parameters.
I had an idea to use

```
while(va_arg(argPtr, char) != NULL)
{
   ...
}
```

to understand when I reach the end of the list. So, will it work, if in function call I'll do `foo(n, 't', 'm', '$', NULL);` ?

Will `NULL` be read as a char by va_arg?
Or maybe there's a more common way to determine the end of list, without adding `NULL` as last parameter?

Comment: if `n` is a format string, then you'd normally just behave like `printf` and family by matching the number of format specifiers against the number of parameters. Are you sure it's just a variable number of `char`s being passed? If so you can match against `-1` or `0` or something, but NULL is a bad idea for the reasons outlined by @hvd in his comments below.

Comment: @kekyc if you are relying on negative `char` values then you should be using `signed char`, if you're only dealing with values in the [0, 128) range (ascii) then -1 should be fine.

Comment: If you're passing a variable-length list of `char` arguments, why not just pass a string? (There are *some* cases where that wouldn't work, but it's the obvious solution.)

Comment: If you have a variable number of parameters of the same type, terminated by a special value, then that value needs to match the type of arguments.  If you're passing `int` values, then you need to pick some special `int` value such as 0 or -1.  If you're passing strings, i.e. `char *`, then you need to terminate it with `(char *) NULL`, as for example `execl()` requires.

Comment: Ok, thank you, guys, for awesome, full answers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no *direct* way for a function that uses `va_arg` to determine the number or type(s) of the arguments passed by a given call.

Your proposed method in particular:

```
while(va_arg(argPtr, char) != NULL)
```

is incorrect. `va_arg(argPtr, char)` yields a value of type `char`, while `NULL` is a null pointer constant. (`NULL` is commonly defined as `0`, which compares equal to the null character `'\0'`, but you can't rely on that.)

Any variadic function must have a way for the caller to specify the number and types of arguments. The `*printf` functions, for example, do so via the (non-variadic) format string. The POSIX `execl*()` functions expect a sequence of `char*` arguments; the end of the argument list is marked by the caller with `(char*)NULL`. Other methods are possible, but they almost all depend on information given at run time in the arguments. (You *could* use some other method, such as a global variable. Please don't.)

This places a burden on the caller to ensure that the arguments passed to the function are consistent. The function itself has no way to confirm this. Incorrect calls, like `printf("%d\n", "hello")` or `execlp("name", "arg1")` have *undefined behavior*.

One more thing: you can't use `va_arg` with an argument of type `char`. When you call a variadic function, arguments corresponding to the `, ...` are *promoted*.  Integer arguments of types narrower than `int` are promoted to `int` or to `unsigned int`, and arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double`. If a caller passes an argument of type `char`, the function must invoke `va_arg(argPtr, int)`.

(In very obscure circumstances that you're not likely to run into, `char` can be promoted to `unsigned int`. That can happen only if plain `char` is unsigned and `sizeof (int) == 1`, which implies that a byte is at least 16 bits.)

Comment: Very nice and complete.  Obscure methods include a global variable or _something_ amongst the arguments (not necessarily a ending sentinel).  Yet the 2 ways mentioned by this fine answer are the most common.

Comment: @chux: Good point about global variables. I've added appropriate weasel words.

Comment: I recall these weak coding practices from the days when `foo(...)` was allowed - pre C89.

Comment: @chux: Interesting. I didn't know that pre-ANSI variadic functions (presumably using `<varargs.h>` to fetch their arguments) used the `...` syntax.

Comment: Even some C99 compilers allowed [zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro#Declaration_syntax) args as an extension.  If the syntax was `...` or not, I may have remembered incorrectly - but the point is that _zero_ args _were_ coded at some point in the passed as an extension and/or pre-C89.  It was rarely useful.

Comment: Isn't `NULL` explicitly interpreted as `((void* )0x0)`. Assigning it to an integer type should produce a warning.

Comment: @Edenia: In C, `NULL` expands to "an implementation-defined null pointer constant". A null pointer constant is defined as "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type`void *`". So `NULL` could expand to any of `((void*)0)`, or `0`, or `('-'-'-')` if the implementer is in a perverse mood. Whether `int n = NULL;` will produce a diagnostic depends on the implementation. (Note that C++ has different rules.)

Answer (score 5):

Just a few years late at this point, but I have some interesting contributions. In this case, I would use the pre-processor. Be warned of incorrect types with variadics btw.

Note: Parenthesizing the function name will make macros ignore it **while allowing the file symbols to not be different than the API** (other than macro usage).

### Method 1: Sentinel Macro

Mask your functions as so:

```c
#define my_func(...) my_func(__VA_ARGS__, NULL);
void (my_func)(...)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

### Method 2: Array Length Macro

Cast the variadic to a `int[]`, to statically determine `sizeof` said array:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))              
#define NARGS(...) ARRAY_LENGTH((int[])({ __VA_ARGS__ }))
```

Similarly mask, but add a count argument in front:

```c
#define my_func(...) my_func(NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__);
void (my_func)(int n, ...)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

### Compile-Specific Type Checking For the Array Macro:

Outside the scope of the question, but since I'm on a [roll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ).

I always use GCC, and sometimes utilize the following. I believe there are semi-compatible features in Clang, but I'm not sure. This allows you to be sure an actual array is being passed and not a pointer.

```c
#define TYPE_COMPATABLE(x, y) __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__(x), __typeof__(y))
#define CHOOSE_EXPR(b, x, y) __builtin_choose_expr((b), (x), (y))
#define IS_ARRAY(a) (!TYPE_COMPATABLE((a), &(a)[0]))
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(a)                           \
    ({                                            \
        _Static_assert(IS_ARRAY(a), "non-array"); \
        sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]);               \
    })

#define NARGS(...) ARRAY_LENGTH((int[])({ __VA_ARGS__ }))
```

At that point, might just use C++ hehe.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea would work. But you've filled in the details in a way that almost certainly won't.

The usual implicit conversion rules don't apply when you're using variadic arguments. Instead, *default argument promotions* take place, which means that any integer type smaller than `int`/`unsigned int` gets converted to one of those -- that's not the only promotion, but the only one relevant here -- and which also means that there is no automatic conversion to whatever type you specify with `va_arg`.

This means that:

- You cannot ever use `va_arg(..., char)`, since it's impossible to pass a `char` as a variadic function argument.
- You cannot ever pass `NULL` as a variadic function argument, since its concrete type is heavily implementation-dependent. Realistic types are `int`, `long`, `void *`, and there are loads of other less realistic but equally valid types.

You could change

> ```
> while(va_arg(argPtr, char) != NULL)
> ```

to

```
while(va_arg(argPtr, int) != 0)
```

and the call

> ```
> foo(n, 't', 'm', '$', NULL);
> ```

to

```
foo(n, 't', 'm', '$', 0);
```